# Command Line Printing to Acrobat is Slow

Tags: command-line-arguments, acrobat

I have a set of PDF documents that prints very slowly via a command line call to the Acrobat Reader executable that skips the Print dialog, versus including the Print dialog (or using the Acrobat GUI).

When I use this command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "C:\0003.pdf" "OKI C9650(PS)"
```

It opens Acrobat, skips the print dialog, but takes about 180 seconds to print.

However, if I print the file through the Acrobat's print dialog, it prints in about 20 seconds.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 8.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /P "C:\0003.pdf"
```

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: I see there is a vote to close this question. If anyone else believes it should be closed, please leave a comment explaining why. I prefer to improve the question and welcome your feedback.

Comment: The reason for my close vote was because this question has nothing to do with programming. Acrobat is end-user software, and your question is about running it as a command-line utility, not with automation. Your question is better suited for [su], as it's a general software use question instead of a programming question. (If you were asking about not being able to print using automation from your app, it would be on topic. If your issue was with launching it via command line using CreateProcess or ShellExecute, it would be on-topic. Your question is about the performance of AcroRd32.exe.